# Can I Re-Install Windows 8.1 on the Same PC After Updating the HDD?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I have a PC and I want to upgrade the SSD from a 64GB to a 256GB.

The upgrade instructions says I can't transfer it to a new *computer*, but I only want to take out the SSD, put in a new one, and cleanly install Windows again in the same computer, at which point I want to store the original SSD offline as a backup image.

Will I need to deactivate Windows 8.1 on the first SSD?

Comment: A new HDD does not create a new computer.  Microsoft only considers a new motherboard as a "new computer" in relation to activation rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can install Windows 8.1 on the same PC after switching out the hard drive. People do this all the time, and I have done it myself on several occasions. Just be sure that if you plan to use the hard drive elsewhere, you remove that copy of Windows. Hard drives with data on them pose not only a security concern if you are going to dispose of it, but if you plan to use the hard drive elsewhere and Microsoft catches the same license being used in two places, you could run in to trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific reason to reinstall W8.1 on the new SSD, I would either clone or image your current system to the new SSD. **[Free Macrium](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/73828-imaging-free-macrium.html?ltr=I)** is a good tool for that.

And here is **[another tutorial](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/149969-ssd-install-transfer-operating-system.html)** that explains how to transfer the OS from one disk to another.

Comment: @whs- How about you supply us with the tutorial(s) directly on this website and/or quote the relevant information(s)?

Comment: I think despite the accepted answer being a bit better, this is still a good answer that provides some extra info.

Comment: @Ramhound -  Good idea but too much work especially since the editor on this site is not Word compatible. Most ofl the originals of more than 100 of my tutorials are in Word - some are in PowerPoint like this one ==> http://www.authorstream.com/Presentation/whs37-2075927-power-point-tutorial/ Try to fit that here.

Comment: @whs - If I am going to do that I might as well write my own tutorial and submit my own answer.  This isn't the first time you have been asked to provide the relevant information in the answer by myself.  The last time I said something you ended up just removing the answer, I hate to see that happen again, the system counts that multiple times against you.

Comment: Answers only using links should be comments!